# Open a modal and fetch data from server on click of a button outside the component

Tags: vue.js

I am very new to Vue.js. In fact I just started today.

I have a problem.

Let's say I have button in a table somewhere in dom.

```
<table>
   <tr><td><button v-on:click="showModal">Show</button>
</table>
```

Now I have a modal box outside of the scope of the button.

This button is inside a component of itself and the modal box has a component of itself too.

I am passing in an id with this button, and what I want to do is:

1. Fetch the id on button click
2. Show the record fetched in the modal and then finally perform some action on it

My problem is I am unable to get a method in the Modal component (that does a http request and fetches and renders the data) to trigger by the click event of this button.

The button and the modal has no relationship, they are not parent/child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option was to add the event broadcast in the common ancestor of both the components.

Like this:

```
var main = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    components: {
        zmodal : zmodal,
        showhidebtn : showhidebtn,
    },
    methods: {
        showModal: function (currentId) {
            this.$broadcast('openModalBox', currentId);
        }
      }
 });
```

Add an event listener in 'zmodal' and call this function showModal from on click event of 'showhidebtn' component.

It is working but now I have a set of codes outside the components that have to be triggered for this to work.

I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In modal component trigger method to fetch data by component ready state:

```
ready: function() {
    this.getAllTheDataYouNeed();
  },
```

You may use another life cycle hook:

https://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: Yes but I would still need to get that variable 'currentId'.

Comment: Past it as as prop to modal component.